# Multi GPU mining broken since upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, scrypt

This is related to scrypt mining.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and after a bit of a hassle I have got almost everything working, except my mining. The issue seems to be a mismatch between OpenCL and ADL. I get different outputs from `cgminer -n` depending on if I prefix it with `sudo`

Without `sudo`:

```
[2014-11-11 21:03:19] CL Platform 0 vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:19] CL Platform 0 name: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:19] CL Platform 0 version: OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3)                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:19] Platform 0 devices: 1                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:19]   0   Pitcairn                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:19] ADL found more devices than opencl!                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:19] There is possibly at least one GPU that doesn't support OpenCL                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:19] Use the gpu map feature to reliably map OpenCL to ADL                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:19] WARNING: Number of OpenCL and ADL devices did not match!                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:19] Hardware monitoring may NOT match up with devices!                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:19] GPU 0 AMD Radeon R9 200 Series hardware monitoring enabled                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:19] 1 GPU devices max detected
```

With `sudo`:

```
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] CL Platform 0 vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] CL Platform 0 name: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] CL Platform 0 version: OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3)                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] Platform 0 devices: 2                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59]   0   Pitcairn                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59]   1   Pitcairn                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] Failed to ADL_Adapter_ID_Get. Error -1                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] Failed to ADL_Adapter_ID_Get. Error -1                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] ADL found less devices than opencl!                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] There is possibly more than one display attached to a GPU                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] Use the gpu map feature to reliably map OpenCL to ADL                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] WARNING: Number of OpenCL and ADL devices did not match!                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] Hardware monitoring may NOT match up with devices!                    
[2014-11-11 21:03:59] 2 GPU devices max detected
```

Without `sudo` I can mine on one GPU with hardware monitoring/overclocking.
With `sudo` I can mine on both GPUs without hardware monitoring.

I think the issue is something to do with `**Failed to ADL_Adapter_ID_Get. Error -1` - but I have no idea how to fix it.

I have tried running `aticonfig --initial` with and without `--adapter=all` and `-f`. I'm at a bit of a loss. Is it possible the upgrade removed some required driver file?

Comment: In typical fashion - I find the answer, after days of searching, 5 minutes after asking :/ this link did it for me: http://prismsoul.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/installing-ubuntus-fglrx-proprietary-catalyst-drivers/